# pandas merged data length

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames, each has one column with the same values (and equal length) but different order as in simplified example;

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(['a','b','c','d','e'],columns=['names'])
df2=pd.DataFrame(['b','e','a','c','d'],columns=['names'])
```

I want to know  the corresponding index of each row in df1 in df2 and do;

```
df= pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), on=['names'])
```

this works and as expected for this example,the length of the data frames are equal `len(df1)=len(df2)=len(df)`

However in my real data, len(df1)=len(df2)=1714  and len(df)=1676

I am puzzled, how is this possible?

I just did an experiment and added duplicates.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(['e','a','b','c','d','e'],columns=['names'])
df2=pd.DataFrame(['b','e','a','e','c','d'],columns=['names'])
df= pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), on=['names'])
```

This gives len(df)=8 larger than len(df1)=len(df2)=6.

But in my real data df is smaller than individual df lengths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `pandas` `merge` default is inner join , when you not specific the method of `how` , it will only output the row both in two dfs

For example :

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(['a'],columns=['names'])
df2=pd.DataFrame(['b','e','a','c','d'],columns=['names'])
pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2.reset_index(), on=['names'])
   index_x names  index_y
0        0     a        2
```

Update

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(['a','a'],columns=['names'])
df2=pd.DataFrame(['b','e','a','a','c','d'],columns=['names'])

df1.merge(df2)
  names
0     a
1     a
2     a
3     a
```

Comment: Thanks W-B, but I have the same values in both data frame, they are just in different order.

Comment: @kutlus after you have duplicate keys , it will merge the same key twice

Comment: sorry, no, it didn't, because in my data df1 and df2 have equal length. The problem I can`t understand is why the length of merged data is less than len(df1)  or len(df2). Maybe I am missing something in your solution. But your comment was still helpful and I voted for you, thanks

Comment: @kutlus let us run`df1.names.isin(df2.names.tolist()).all()` is this return False ?

Comment: I did run it, it said 'False'. I guess some values are different in two data frames even though they shouldn`t be, so I didn`t think that would be the reason. This solved my question, many thanks